# Change NotificationBar behavior from Java

Tags: java, primefaces

I need to hide my notificationBar after 60 seconds. But i don't have a commandButton in my form. I need to do hide my notificationBar from my ManagedBean. Any tips?

Comment: Could you please share the code that you tried and explain the difficulties with more details

Comment: Assuming there is no faces context: Use push! Send an event to the client and use that to hide the bar

Comment: So do you need to hide it after 60 seconds OR on a signal from your ManagedBean? If it's just about the 60 seconds then it's trivial to make a client-side only solution (and Push would be an overkill).